# Add a modal popup when the mass action button in ui component admin grid

Tags: grid, massaction, modal-popup

I have a admin grid, where I want to add a popup which will have a input field posting a data on confirmation.

[image: Admin grid mass action]

Take the above screenshot as an example. When the hold button is clicked, I want to display a modal popup which will have a input field in it.

PS: I tried to make the confirm method in the ui component but it didn't work, If any other idea is there to make this, it will be helpful. Thanks!